# how to get the delete row value if I wanna to delete it in gridview (web application)

Tags: c#, asp.net

when i have a gridview, after the user press the delete button, i will like to know that the particular row data in this case, how i get the particular row data?

Sample gridview:

```
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="addCartID" 
                    BackColor="White" 
                    BorderColor="White" BorderStyle="Ridge" BorderWidth="2px" CellPadding="3" 
                    CellSpacing="1" GridLines="None" OnRowDeleted="Delete_Event">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="addCartID" InsertVisible="False" 
                            SortExpression="addCartID">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("addCartID") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("addCartID") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="productID" SortExpression="productID">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("productID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("productID") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="custID" SortExpression="custID">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("custID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("custID") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="seatOrderID" SortExpression="seatOrderID">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("seatOrderID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("seatOrderID") %>'></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>


                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#4A3C8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#E7E7FF" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#C6C3C6" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#DEDFDE" ForeColor="Black" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#9471DE" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#594B9C" />
                    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#33276A" />
                </asp:GridView>
```

Here is the c# code i wanna get the delete value, after user click delete i wish to update something based on the seatOrderID deleted, how do i get it? tq~~

```
 protected void updateBack()
    {
        Response.Write(I want to get the deleted seatOrderID here!!!!!);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this code, you can fetch the ID in the RowDeleting event:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];

        string id = String.Empty;
        Label lbl = (gvr.FindControl("Label1") as Label)

        if (lbl != null)
        {
          id = lbl.Text;
        }
    }
```

You can fetch any control in the row, using the `FindControl()` method.